# Php Array from database not getting desired array stucture

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I have problem with building multi-dimensional array by pulling data from database.
I have a list of Sales Representative (sr)  in my database. I run query and selected all sr.
Now I have to create array like this:

```
array (size=3)
  'Manoj' =>
    array (size=3)
      'mc_count' => 0
      'auto_count' => 0
      'in_count' => 0
  'Bharat' =>
    array (size=3)
      'mc_count' => 0
      'auto_count' => 0
      'in_count' => 0
  'Pradeep' =>
    array (size=3)
      'mc_count' => 0
      'auto_count' => 0
      'in_count' => 0
```

To create this I have written following code:

```
<?php
$sr_array=array();
$sr_sql= "select DISTINCT sr from sales_invoice";
$sr_query = mysqli_query($connection, $sr_sql);
while($sr_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sr_query)){
       $sr_array []= array($sr_result["sr"]=>array(“mc_count”,”auto_count”,”in_coun”);

        }
var_dump($sr_array);

?>
```

I get this OUTPUT

```
array (size=9)
  0 =>
    array (size=1)
      'Manoj' =>
        array (size=3)
          'count_in_battery' => int 10
          'count_auto_battety' => int 0
          'count_indu_battery' => int 0
  1 =>
    array (size=1)
      'Bharat' =>
        array (size=3)
          'count_in_battery' => int 10
          'count_auto_battety' => int 0
          'count_indu_battery' => int 0
  2 =>
    array (size=1)
      'Pradeep =>
        array (size=3)
          'count_in_battery' => int 10
          'count_auto_battety' => int 0
          'count_indu_battery' => int 0
```

If you see the output my array has additional index as

```
0 =>   //Unwanted Index
    array (size=1)
      'Manoj' =>
```

Which is creating problem in programming. If you can please help me.

Comment: Try `$sr_array[$sr_result["sr"]] = array(“mc_count”,”auto_count”,”in_coun”);`.

Comment: `$sr_array = array($sr_result["sr"]=>array(“mc_count”,”auto_count”,”in_coun”);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sr_array = array();
$sr_sql = "select DISTINCT sr from sales_invoice";
$sr_query = mysqli_query($connection, $sr_sql);

while($sr_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sr_query)){
    $sr_array[$sr_result["sr"]] = array(
        "mc_count" => 0,
        "auto_count" => 0,
        "in_coun" => 0
    );
}
```